# I can not install nativescript on windows via npm

Tags: android, windows, npm, nativescript, mobile-development

I want to install NativeScript on windows 10, when I typed:

```
    npm install -g nativescript
```

I got this error message:

```
    D:\workspace\projects>npm install nativescript@next -g
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Abdelaziz\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "nativescript@next" "-g"
    npm ERR! node v4.4.5
    npm ERR! npm  v4.0.0
    npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
    npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
    npm ERR! syscall connect

    npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5080
    npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
    npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5080]
    npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
    npm ERR!   address: '127.0.0.1',
    npm ERR!   port: 5080 }
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
    npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     D:\workspace\projects\npm-debug.log
```

what is the error I made ?

Comment: could you verify, whether the same behavior is happening with the official version of NativeScript. Try to install it with `npm install nativescript -g`

Comment: I get the same error message for both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, it was caused by "local-npm" module. I was not able to npm because I have modified the registry from `https://registry.npmjs.org` to `localhost:5080`.